# Amazon SES Rails mailer on Heroku: InvalidParameterValue - Missing required header 'From'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

RoR mailer environment, SES running production on Heroku and development on my notebook.

I get **Missing required header 'From'** ses error response from production deploy on Heroku.

My header definitely has the 'from' field, I know that because ***I actually get the email*** in my inbox , so SES sent it but then raise the error anyway.

When I run from development environment I can - and do - send thousands of emails from my development computer and receive them in my test emails, everything works just fine. Deploying to Heroku the same exact code, gives that error, but send the email anyway.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug in the beta of SES. I went around this by turning off failure. Not ideal, but needs to move on, especially when it does send the email

in config/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

Comment: I have the same issue and tried this but emails are not delivering. Have you found any proper solution yet?

Comment: It works for me if I turn off the warning. I sent tens of thousands of test emails without missing any.